# Android DatePickerDiaglogue showing a calendar view instead of that in the documentation

Tags: android

I've managed to sucsessfully create a `DatePickerDialog()` but it is opening a calender while i was expecting something that looked more like the dialogue on the right of the following link;

[image: https://developer.android.com/images/ui/pickers.png]

im guessing i shouldn't be creating an instance of `DatePickerDialog()` but im not sure what i should be using instead. please assist.

code is as follows;

```
private void dob() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new CustomDatePicker(), mYear, mMonth, mDay).show();
}

public class CustomDatePicker implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // getCalender();
        int mYear = year;
        int mMonth = monthOfYear;
        int mDay = dayOfMonth;
        /*v.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("/").append(mDay).append("/")
                .append(mYear).append(" "));*/
        //System.out.println(v.getText().toString());


    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra i have edited my question to include the code.

Comment: can you put an image with the calendar that your code is opening?

Comment: looks like your issue is solved in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870035/style-datepicker)

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra I have updated the question to include screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, is default behavior since you are running the app in a `Lollipop` device. The image that you attach (whit blue lines and dark background) belongs to `KitKat` version.

If you really want to customize and keep with the `KitKat` appearance in `Lollipop` devices or above, you have to modify your `styles.xml` to this:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
  <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item>
  <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item> 
</style>
```